# Question about Feller's book on the Central Limit Theorem

Tags: analysis, measure-theory, probability-theory

My question concerns the proof of Theorem 1, section VIII.4, in Vol II of Feller's book 'An Introduction to Probability Theory and its Applications'. Theorem 1 proves the Central Limit Theorem in the i.i.d. zero mean, unit variance case.

In purely analytical terms, this theorem says that if $F$ is a (probability) distribution function with zero expectation and unit variance, then $$F^{n*}(x\sqrt{n}) \rightarrow \mathfrak{N}(x)$$ in the distributional sense (where $\mathfrak{N}$ is the standard normal distribution, and $(\cdot)^{n*}$ denotes the n-fold convolution operation).

To prove this, Feller uses the following (the proof of which I understand):

$\textbf{Lemma}$ $\quad$ Denote by $\mathfrak{F}_n$ the convolution operator associated with the functions $F_n(x):= F(x\sqrt{n})$. Then for any $u : \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ with three bounded derivatives and finite limits at $\pm \infty$, we have the following uniform convergence on the line: $$n[\mathfrak{F}_nu - u] \rightarrow \frac{1}{2}u''. \quad \square $$

Now denote by $\mathfrak{G}$ and $\mathfrak{G}_n$ resoectively the convolution operators associated with the distributions  $\mathfrak{N}(x)$ and  $\mathfrak{N}(x\sqrt{n})$. Then it is easy to derive the following inequality, where the norm is the supremum norm:

$$  \|\mathfrak{F}_n^n(u) - \mathfrak{G}(u) \| \leq n\|\mathfrak{F}_n(u) - u \| + n\|\mathfrak{G}_n(u)-u \| .$$

Now comes the bit I don't understand. He claims that, by the Lemma above, the RHS of this inequality tends to zero. (N.B. He doesn't specify what kind of function $u$ is). How can this be so, unless $u''=0$ on the line? This suggests to me that he is approximating all continuous functions on $\mathbb{R}$ with finite limits at $\pm \infty$ by functions with zero second derivative. I guess this can be done? And do you think this is what Feller is doing at this stage?

Many thanks for your help.

Frank.

Comment: This is rather strange. I find Feller hard to read because of the notations. Anyway, you can certainly not approximate any function $u$ by affine functions. What you *can* do however, is approximate any $u$ like yours by *piecewise affine* functions. Maybe the Lemma in Feller can be adapted??

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand: why should the probability distribution function of the sum be equal to the convolution of the probability distribution functions? (Isn't it a property of the *density* functions?)

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro Because the random variables are assumed to be independent and identically distributed,the distribution of the sum  (of n of the random variables) is the n-fold convolution of their common distribution. Thanks for your help, Frank.

Comment: There might be a terminology conflict here. To me, the *probability distribution function* of a RV $X$ is the following function: 
$$F(x)=P(X\le x),$$
and the *distribution* of $X$ is the following measure:
$$\mu_X(E)=P(X\in E).$$
If $X_1$ and $X_2$ are two iid RV, then the *distribution* of the sum is the convolution of the two distributions. This does not mean that the probability distribution function of the sum is the convolution of the probability distribution functions.

Comment: For a concrete example, take two RV $X_1$ and $X_2$ which are equal to $0$ almost surely.

Comment: Yes, you are right, but probabilists tend to interchange the two notions because your $F$ uniquely determines your $\mu_X$ (because sets of the form $(-\infty, x]$ form a $\pi$-system generating the Borel sigma-algebra on $\mathbb{R}$).

Comment: Ok. So the "convolution" operation here is the convolution of probability measures. I am sorry that those observations do nothing to solve your problem, though. I agree with Etienne's suggestion, by the way.

Comment: I was reading Feller just now and I had exactly the same doubt as you. Further, I think he should have addeded that $\mathfrak{G}$ and $\mathfrak{G}_n^n$ are both the random variable $\mathsf{Norm}(0;1)$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I know I'm probably 3 years late, but I was studying this chapter of the book and hammering my head around this lemma and theorem for half a day before I managed to make sense of it!

In my opinion, i think there is a small mistake on his proof. I would go on to prove it like this:

$$||\frak{F}_n^n u - \frak{G}u|| = ||\frak{F}_n^n u - \frak{G}_n^n u|| \leq n||\frak{F}_n u - \frak{G}_n u|| = ||n(\frak{F}_n u - u) - n(\frak{G}_n u - u)||\to\left|\left|\frac{u^{\prime \prime}}{2} - \frac{u^{\prime \prime}}{2}\right|\right|$$

Then the lemma works like a glove to finish the proof

Comment: That's great, thanks a lot Dyego :)